# How can I send variables to my forms on init in Django?

Tags: django

I want to send variables to a form in my Django project so that my form's save method associates the correct object with the foreign key in the model.

I tried setting it in the init method, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Form's **init**:

```
def __init__(self, rsvp, max_guests=2, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RSVPForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.rsvp = rsvp
    self.max_guests = rsvp.max_guests
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: sorry about that, it's been added.

Comment: Are you talking about a ModelForm here, and you want to associate RSVP with a the *instance* the ModelForm is based on? If so, you want to either do self.instance.rsvp = rsvp etc, or set the rsvp etc in your view code: call instance = form.save(commit=False); instance.rsvp = rsvp; then finally do instance.save() when you're done. Or thereabouts ;o)

Comment: No, this is just a regular form. It draws from a few different objects, and it needs to foreign key to the rsvp object on save.

Comment: Since when do standard forms have `save()` method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for [`initial`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial):

> Use initial  to declare the initial value of form fields at runtime. For example, you might want to fill in a username field with the username of the current session.

Pulling directly from the docs:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
     name = forms.CharField(initial='class')
     url = forms.URLField()
     comment = forms.CharField()
f = CommentForm(initial={'name': 'instance'})
```

This would yield a form with the initial value of `name` being 'instance'.